# A way to use Nvidia Rapids in windows directly?

Tags: machine-learning, jetbrains-ide, rapids, dataspell, cuml

I would Like to know that is there a way to install Nvidia Rapids directly in windows 11 and use rather than using it with wsl2 or docker? Or is there a way to connect jupyter lab host to dataspell?

I tried installing cuMl directly to windows via github but am failing everytime. I want to use cuml in jetbrains dataspell thats why seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

To install RAPIDS locally on Windows, WSL2 is required. Windows native packages are not available. You can refer to the installation guide for more information about supported platforms and how to use WSL2 with conda or Docker images: https://docs.rapids.ai/install

Alternatively, you could use a cloud deployment of RAPIDS. This page lists some of the options for deployment: https://docs.rapids.ai/deployment/stable/